# Screen flickering black after upgrade from 19.04 to 21.04 (ubuntu emulated on virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, performance, 21.04, macosx, flicker

I have a macbook with 10.15.7 and virtualbox 6.1
I just updated ubuntu from 19.04 to 21.04
Now when I login into ubuntu every few (randomly) seconds I get a black screen for a while. It seems a black flickering effect.
I updated guest addition but not solved the issue.

Also I have a performance issue, the system is very slow.

Up to version 20.04 (step before 21.04) it worked properly.

Please may you help me? In this way I cannot use the system

#EDIT
I found the cause, it was a wrong graphic card selection on virtualbox settings. Switched from VBoxVGA to VMSVGA and now it works without flickering. Now I have to solve other issues like slow system performance and it doesn't save display scale settings across sessions.

Comment: There is not a supported upgrade path from 19.04 to 21.04.  19.04 became EOL in January 2020, almost 2 years ago. Successive upgrade paths have also been unsupported for nearly as long. It's not clear why you believe the upgrade was successful when you are having these problems.  If you want any expectation for an upgrade to be successful you must upgrade to the next release *before* the current one goes EOL.  You waited far too long. You should cleanly reinstall a supported release to solve this problem.

Comment: It was a long time that I am not using this virtual machine.
Yesterday, in order to upgrade to 21.04 I did some intermediate upgrade steps. 19.04 -> 19.10 -> 20.04 -> 21.04
I found the cause, it was a wrong graphic card selection on virtualbox settings. Switched from VBoxVGA to VMSVGA and now it works without flickering.
Now I have to solve other issues like slow system performance and it doesn't save display scale settings across sessions.
A cleanly reinstall not solve this two last issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 for a long time in VirtualBox without any performance issues. And updated it to 21.10. System performance became very poor after that. I found the solution in [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359711/enabling-3d-acceleration-in-virtualbox-makes-xubuntu-display-extremely-laggy).

Uncheck the "Enable 3D Acceleration" box in Display tab of your virtual machine configuration. "3D Acceleration" feature is still "experimental".

[image: virtual machine configuration]